# how to detect if Aero Peek mode is on

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, aero, peek

I'm trying to find out how to detect if windows desktop [Aero Peek](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/peek.aspx) mode is on. In particular I'm need to detect if my window content is shown or drawn as a frame with transparent background. I know I can exclude my window from Aero Peek, but this not what I need at this moment.

TIA

Comment: Can you use DwmSetIconicThumbnail() and check for WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL messages? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819048(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your desktop would go into this "*Aero Peek*" mode when user is *peeking* windows by hovering mouse over taskbar icons. You can use [windows event hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to trace if "**Task Switcher**" object is shown, combined with DWM mode on it should tell you if user is peeking a window. Below is an application I made to test this idea (c++, let me know if there are problems converting it to c#).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <Oleacc.h>
#include <iostream>

#define THREAD_MESSAGE_EXIT     WM_USER + 2000

HWINEVENTHOOK eventHook;
HWND taskSwitcherHwnd = 0;

// process event
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW) 
    {
        IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
        VARIANT varChild;       
        HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);  
        if (hr == S_OK && pAcc != NULL)
        {
            BSTR accName;
            pAcc->get_accName(varChild, &accName);
            if (wcscmp(accName, L"Task Switcher")==0)
            {
                std::cout << "Aero Peek on\n";
                taskSwitcherHwnd = hwnd;
            }
            SysFreeString(accName);
            pAcc->Release();
        }
    }
    else if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE && taskSwitcherHwnd!=0 && taskSwitcherHwnd==hwnd)
    {
        std::cout << "Aero Peek off\n";
        taskSwitcherHwnd = 0;
    }
}

// thread proc for messages processing
// needed for event's hook to work
DWORD WINAPI TreadProc(LPVOID n)
{
    std::cout << "InitializeEventHook\n";
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    eventHook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE,   
        NULL, HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, 
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);   

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (msg.message==THREAD_MESSAGE_EXIT) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "ShutdownEventHook\n";
    UnhookWinEvent(eventHook);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Detect Aero Peek\n";

    DWORD threadId;
    int value = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, TreadProc, &value, 0, &threadId);

    char a;
    std::cin >> a;

    PostThreadMessage(threadId, THREAD_MESSAGE_EXIT, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10000);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

    public bool IsAeroActive()
    {
        // Check if Aero is enabled;
        if (DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool aeroEnabled = IsAeroActive();

        if (aeroEnabled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aero is enabled.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aero is disabled.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you really need the IsAeroActive method?  why not call the API directly?

Comment: you don't have to have the IsAeroActive method, just the way I have coded it to try to make it easier to read

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for, your code detects if DWM is on, whereas I'm trying to detect if desktop is currently in Aero Peek mode. You can start it if hover the mouse over task bar buttons, whenever a window thumbnail pops up means Aero Peek is on

Comment: @Nadine Surely AeroPeek is on if and only if DWM composition is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you read from windows Registry, there you can find the status of Aero Peek

> \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM

Is a DWORD value named **EnableAeroPeek** which is set as following:

> *1* = Enabled 
>   *0* = disabled

Just compare to 0 or 1 to find out if AeroPeek is on.

In C# something like this:

```
Using Microsoft.Win32;
```

...

```
RegistryKey AeroPeek = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM", true);
       if ((int)AeroPeek.GetValue("EnableAeroPeek") == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aero Peek is ON");
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Aero Peek is OFF");
```

You can also change those values and instantly Aero Peek status will change.